# JS window.onload doesn't load my function

Tags: forms, validation

I've got JS form validation code and have to write HTML to it. Unfortunately, something is wrong. Could you please tell me what I am doing wrong? When I click submit button there is no change.

```js
window.onload = init;

        function validateForm() {
            var user = document.forms["myForm"]["user"].value;
            var password = document.forms["myForm"]["password"].value;
            if (user == "") {
                document.getElementById("poleUser").innerHTML = "<img src='./unchecked.gif'/> Proszę podać nazwisko";
            } else {
                document.getElementById("poleUser").innerHTML = "<img src='./checked.gif'/>";
            }
            if (password.lenght < 6) {
                document.getElementById("poleHasla").innerHTML =
                    "<img src='./unchecked.gif'/> Hasło musi zawierać co najmnej 6 znaków";
            } else {
                document.getElementById("poleHasla").innerHTML = "<img src='./checked.gif'/>";
            }
            return false;
        }

        function init() {
            document.getElementsByName('myForm').onsubmit = validateForm;
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

</head>

<body>

    <form name="myForm">
        Name: <input type="texts" name="user"><span id="poleUser"></span><br>
        Password: <input type="password" name="password"><span id="poleHasla"></span>
        <br>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to properly format the function calls

`document.getElementsByName('myForm').onsubmit = validateForm;`
should be
`document.getElementsByName('myForm').onsubmit = validateForm();`

(Notice the parentheses at the end).

However, I'd just like to address **how** you're doing this. In most cases, assigning the `onSubmit` property statically makes more sense than doing it dynamically. In this case, there really doesn't seem to be any reason for initializing the property using JS.